# How do the standard define a C program?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

I am studying on how to make a bytecode interpreter (the language i am studing is clox at the site https://craftinginterpreters.com/). In it a valid clox program is defined as a list of declarations. A declaration is defined as either a class, function or variable declaration OR as a statement.

Now in C, i know there are different kinds of declarations and there are different kinds of statements but none of the types of declarations are a statement and none of the type of statements are a declaration. I think any possible line of C code is either one or the other so how do the standard define a C program ?

A list of lines that can be either a definition or a statement ?

Comment: I mean in a nutshell a C program is statements and expressions but if you want to know the full details then you got to read the standard for yourself. Even just glancing through cppreference.com/w/c you can get a good understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard defines a translation unit (effectively the source file being compiled, including all the files it includes with `#include`) as a list of *external-declaration* items, and each *external-declaration* is either a *function-definition* or a *declaration* (C 2018 6.9 1).

So, fundamentally, each source file of a C program is a list of declarations, including function definitions.

Each *function-definition* has, after the part that declares the type(s) of the function and its parameter(s), a *compound-statement* (6.9.1 1). A *compound-statement* is a list of *declaration* or *statement* items enclosed in `{` and `}` (6.8.2 1).

Each *declaration* tells us about (usually<sup>1</sup>) one or more identifiers (6.8 2 and 5). A *statement* is some sort of instruction for the computer to “do something,” such as iterate a loop or evaluate an expression. In the C grammar, there is no overlap between declarations and statements.

Further information on declarations is in clause 6.7 of the C 2018 standards, and further information on statements is in clause 6.8.

### Footnote

1 In the C grammar, a *static_assert-declaration* is also a declaration. It does not declare any identifier but creates a compile-time assertion that is tested and that produces an error message if the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

A C program is defined by its grammar and the details of the implementation defined in the standard. [Get yourself a copy of the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents), any version will do for the basics, and look at the grammar. A summary of the grammar can be found in Annex A.

Section 6.8 defines a statement as being one of any number of specific types of statements.

```
statement:
  labeled-statement
  compound-statement
  expression-statement
  selection-statement
  iteration-statement
  jump-statement
```

It goes on to provide more detail, for example, it tells us the order in which statements are executed.

> A statement specifies  an  action  to  be  performed.   Except  as  indicated,  statements are executed in sequence.

And you drill down deeper. For example, 6.8.4 defines a `selection-statement` which covers the basic control structures if, else, and switch.

```
selection-statement:
  if (expression) statement
  if (expression) statement else statement
  switch (expression) statement
```

Note how statements can be build of more statements.

And in this way the grammar of the language is built up.

Comment: Nice answer, maybe you could also answer my question on loops

Comment: You can refer to the standard for details on the other kinds of statements.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Which question are you referring to?

Comment: @Schwern You can see a question on "number of loops in C++" in my profile

Comment: @ArdentCoder I'd have to read through the C++ grammar, but you can do that as well as I can. I wouldn't expect that sort of question in an interview; you don't need to memorize language trivia to be a good programmer. If I were to ask this in an interview, there would be no right answer. I'd want to hear your process of working it out, just like in Ayxan's answer.

Comment: @Schwern Oh I see, thanks

Comment: This answer discusses only *statements* and fails to discuss or distinguish *declarations*, which the question asks about and which are distinct from statements in the C standard.